# Rails: Page loading very long time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loading

I have a rails project.
I got very strange thing in one controller: browser needs about 3 minutes for load page but Rails writes in logs:

```
Completed 200 OK in 20563ms (Views: 17144.2ms | ActiveRecord: 324.4ms)
```

I know 21 sec it's very long time, but It's not 3 minutes.
[image: Data from a browser]

I know this data not enough but I don't expect complete answer only a pointer where is trouble. 
Size of this page about 5 Mb.

Comment: Are you using a CDN to serve the assets on your page?  Are you also seeing this behavior locally or just in prod?  Do most of your images come from other sites or are they stored in your asset pipeline?

Comment: Post a screenshot of the "Network" tab in chrome developer console so we can see exactly which request is taking how long.

Comment: Also make sure you arent doing a `n+1` style query. That is a simple mistake to make when you are calling associations in template views.

Answer (score 3):

The delay might be caused by `config.assets.debug = true` inside of `config/environments/development.rb`. Setting this to `false` may resolve your problem.

> By doing this,source files are combined together and source maps won't
>   work (e.g. if using Sass/Coffee you won't see it in devtools)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the most of the time is spent in "idle" phase. This includes the time to load all resources on your page (images, stylesheets, javascript, etc.). So, your HTML page is being loaded and rendered in 10 seconds, but the rest is spent to download all the resources in your page.

This can be a single resources that is hosted on some server that is just very slow on responding to your request. So, even if you have a loaded all content, but you have a Google hosted jquery file there and really bad internet connection, then you would see that "idle" to take up a lot of time.

But, in your case, it looks like some images on your 5MB page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 5Mb it's only data from Rails server (very big table). I have noticed: after  rails write complete message in logs and before browser receive date ruby process take 50% of processor. I think maybe a problem  on middleware side.

Comment: Probably you have a dual core processor and Ruby is eating up 100% of your CPU time. That might be some middleware processing your response, but you can optimise your page rendering by [streaming your page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html) as it is generated, instead of waiting till it is all rendered and only then sending it to client.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem after long search.
It was unnecessary query to database which loaded many related objects for main objects. But I didn't understand why it required such many time (maybe GC clean it mess).