# Rails: Waiting too long for showing modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a Rails app showing a modal but it takes ages to display. How can I find a problem, why is it happening?

- I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056561/rails-page-loading-very-long-time) answer indicating a problem with includes - but I have my page already loaded and need to show only a simple modal popup.
- I checked my internet connection. Seems fine, and the rest of the website loads normally.
  [image]
- Basically it is a dashboard with a list of events. When you hit "+" button, a modal should show up and you should be able to add an attendant.

So the event row.haml looks like this:

```
    = link_to new_admin_attendance_path(event_id: event.id, date: params[:date]), 
remote: true, class: 'btn btn-success' do %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
```

When I click on the "+" button, new attendance code looks like this:

```
def new
    @attendance = Attendance.new

    if params[:event_id]
      @attendance.event_id = params[:event_id]
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

- I also checked the database which is PostgreSQL and there is an index on the row event_id on the Attendances table.
- This is a screenshot from Inspect->Network. What is being downloaded 16 seconds? (My colleague mentioned it took sometimes 2 minutes) [image]

  - After hitting "+" in dev environment, this is written in console:

[image]

- I don't have access to the production database. I can only log to the AWS with ssh but no idea how to work with it.

Comment: Does your console show anything helpful?

Comment: @jvillian I can't answer this question since I don't know how to work with the production :-X But when I run the app locally with a DB dump (almost 10 times less data), it runs nicely, check the event id: "event_id"=>"1935". On production it is "event_id=14814" and it takes 16 seconds. I guess there might be a problem with the database performance?

Comment: The code that you showed does not cause any query to be run. If you're worried about database performance, just run the query in rails console/directly in DB and check instead of guessing.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej There are 4 queries triggered by hitting the "+" button. All are selects from associated tables with the table Attendance and they join data necessary for inserting a new attendance record. It works fine in dev env, but the prod is slow.

Comment: Eventually, I found something weird, one query is being executed 3 times - it's select count * from one table where a column is null.

Comment: You may want to edit your question with the generated queries, partial code (which I assume is causing the queries to be run), your models and optionally an `EXPLAIN` statement run on the slow queries.

Comment: @IvankaEldé well, you are loading all customers from database for some reason. We don't see the code responsible for that so it is difficult to say anything more, but assuming you have a lot of customers in production this will take a really long time.